# python getting the maximum date and maximum time from the input sequence

Tags: python-3.x, date, time

I want to get the maxim date and maximum time when user inputs 10-12 numbers separated by space or comma

I tried the code for the date but I'm getting stuck in creating a logic for getting the maximum month with date 
what I did was first sorted the list in descending order and then check in the resultent list that if the number is less than or equal to 1 then it is placed on 0th index and then if the 0th index number is 1 then the number on 1st index will be less than or equal to 2

```
digits = [int(x) for x in input("Enter the digits").split(",")]
date = []

print(digits)

for x in range(0, len(digits)):
    for y in range(0, len(digits) - x - 1):
        if digits[y] <= digits[y + 1]:
            temp = digits[y]
            digits[y] = digits[y + 1]
            digits[y + 1] = temp

print(digits)

for x in range(0, len(digits)):
    if digits[x] <= 1:
        date.insert(0, digits[x])
        break

digits.remove(digits[x])
print("digits ", digits)
print(date)

for y in range(0, len(digits) - 1):
    if date[0] == 1:
        while digits[y] >= 0 and digits[y] <= 2:
            if digits[y] >= digits[y + 1]:
                date.insert(1, digits[y])
                digits.remove(digits[y])
                break
    if date[0] < 1:
        while digits[y] >= 0 and digits[y] <= 9:
            if digits[y] >= digits[y + 1]:
                date.insert(1, digits[y])
                digits.remove(digits[y])
                break
    break
print("digits", digits)

for x in range(0, len(digits)):
    if digits[x] <= 3:
        date.insert(2, digits[x])
        break

digits.remove(digits[x])
print(date)

print("digits", digits)

for y in range(0, len(digits)):
    if date[2] == 3:
        while digits[y] >= 0 and digits[y] <= 1:
            if digits[y] >= digits[y + 1]:
                date.insert(3, digits[y])
                digits.remove(digits[y])
                break
    if date[2] < 3:
        while digits[y] >= 0 and digits[y] <= 9:
            if digits[y] >= digits[y + 1]:
                date.insert(3, digits[y])
                digits.remove(digits[y])
                break
    break

print(date)
```

now in the above code when I give inputs

```
input : 1,0,0,1,1
output :
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
digits  [1, 1, 0, 0]
[1]
digits [1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
digits [0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
```

So here 1,1,1,0 is 11 month and 10 is the days
So the format should be MMDD including zeros
but when I give other input like

```
input : 1,2,3,1,1
output :
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
digits  [3, 2, 1, 1]
[1]
digits [3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 3]
digits [2, 1, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "date.py", line 51, in <module>
    if date[2] == 3:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here I wanted 1,2,3,1 as 12 as month and 31 as days

Comment: Don't really understand how the input digits relate to dates, can you elaborate? What does each digit supposed to represent?

Comment: Digits is the input i from the user

Comment: That is understandable from the code, what I don't understand is what each digit means. Years? Months? Days?

Comment: Only months and days

Comment: I'll edit output type

Comment: I edited the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime, itertools

dates = []
try:
    digits = [int(x) if int(x) < 10 else 100 for x in input("Enter the digits").split(",")]
    if 100 in digits:
        raise ValueError('Must be digits and not numbers')
    date_perms = itertools.permutations(digits, 4)
    for date in date_perms:
        dates.append((date[0]*10+date[1], date[2]*10+date[3]))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

for i, date in enumerate(dates):
    try:
        dates[i] = datetime.datetime(year=1, month=date[0], day=date[1])
    except ValueError as e:
        dates[i] = datetime.datetime(1,1,1,1)
if len(dates) > 0:
    maximum = max(dates)
    if maximum.hour == 1:
        print('None of the combinations created a valid date')
    else:
        print('Month:', maximum.month, 'Day:', maximum.day)
```

I think this might do what you need. `itertools.permutations` creates all the possible combinations of the given digits.
The 2nd try-except block will replace the faulty dates with `Year=1, month=1, day=1, hour=1`. The others will have 0 hour.

Also, notice I replaced your input list comprehension a bit. It previously allowed non-int input as well as non-digit. When a non-digit is entered (>9) I place a 100 in the list and then check whether there is one and throw an exception.

**Edit based on comment:**

```
dates = []
try:
    digits = [int(x) if int(x) < 10 else 100 for x in input("Enter the digits").split(",")]
    if 100 in digits:
        raise ValueError('Must be digits and not numbers')
    datetime_perms = itertools.permutations(digits, 8)
    for date_time in datetime_perms:
        convert_date = []
        for skip in range(0,8,2):
            # Create a list that will look like [Month, Day, Hour, Minute]
            convert_date.append(date_time[skip]*10+date_time[skip+1])
        dates.append(convert_date)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

for i, date in enumerate(dates):
    try:
        dates[i] = datetime.datetime(year=1, month=date[0], day=date[1], hour=date[2], minute=date[3])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(dates[i])
        dates[i] = datetime.datetime(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
if len(dates) > 0:
    maximum = max(dates)
    if maximum.microsecond == 1:
        print('None of the combinations created a valid date')
    else:
        print('Month:', maximum.month, 'Day:', maximum.day, 'Hour:', maximum.hour, 'Minute:', maximum.minute)
```

This should do what you need. For the input of `1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0` I received the output of `Month: 12 Day: 31 Hour: 23 Minute: 40`

Comment: Thankyou soo much it worked now the thing is while moving forward I when I input all the digits I need the maximum time in the output as well that means if I have input in 0,0,1,2,2,2,3,5,9,9,9,9 I want to get the output 12/30 22:59 can we get this kind of output coz I think we cant I am not able to think the next thing

Comment: @BhushanPatil Editted the answer.

Comment: You are the best I'll try to understand it 
Can you give me advice from and how should I learn python coz I am beginer in it I want to make myself better in java and python can suggest me please

Comment: Why was range in convert date is till 8 and why do we converted it can you explain it?

Comment: I wanted that for loop in order to avoid typing `(date_time[0]*10+date_time[1], date_time[2]*10+date_time[3], date_time[4]*10+date_time[5], date_time[6]*10+date_time[7])`. This way I only need to change 1 thing if I want to add something else and make it add more things. It basically runs from 0 and until 7 (There are 8 digits what you requested, 2 for month, 2 for day etc).  
We basically convert it because I want to combine 2 digits into 1 number, that will represent one of the numbers needed for the date and time.

Comment: As an artefact, I think your answer is a pioneer in having an input in a list comprehension. )

Comment: Can't take the credit for this, I believe I saw it somewhere before.